# Form::select Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Estou tendo dificuldade em fazer um `Form:select` que busca informação do banco de dados.

Como esta o `Controller`;

```
public function create() 
{   
    return View('internos.create');
}
```

Como está na `View`;

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('setor', 'Setor: ') }}
  {{ Form::select('setor_id', 
       array(''=>'Selecione...')+ Setor::all()->lists('descricao', 'id'), 
       null, array('class'=>'form-control'))  
  }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, o dado tem um trafego do `Controller` para `View` e vice-versa, mas, nunca a `View` gerar essa informação diretamente, exemplo de modificação do seu `Controller` ***método***:

```php
public function create() 
{   
    $setors = Setor::pluck('descricao', 'id')
    $setors[''] = 'Selecione...';
    return View('internos.create', ['setors' => $setors]);
    // ou return View('internos.create', compact('setors'));
}
```

Na sua `View` faça as seguintes modificações:

```php
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('setor', 'Setor: ') }}
  {{ Form::select('setor_id', $setors, null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

ou seja, na sua `View` só tem a variável com as informações para sua geração e não lógica isso fica no seu `Controller`.

Comment: Executei esta rotina e deu o seguinte erro:

public function create() 
    {
        $setors = Setor::all()->lists('descricao', 'id');
        $setors[''] = 'Selecione...';
 
        return View('internos.create', ['setors' => $setors]);
    }

"Class 'App\Http\Controllers\RH\Setor' not found"

Comment: @AguinaldoTupy você precisa adicionar o namespace do Setor! no seu controller

Comment: Amigo, continuo com problema =/

"Method lists does not exist."

Comment: Eu fiz uma alteração na minha pergunta tem que ser assim `$setors = Setor::pluck('descricao', 'id')` @AguinaldoTupy

Comment: Shoooow
Eternamente grato pela ajuda!

O método return View('internos.create', compact('$setors')); não vai... Porém, deu certo com o outro método.

Paz e alegria!

Comment: Se for util vote nela para a resposta da sua pergunta, vai sim estava escrito errado fiz uma nova edição @AguinaldoTupy